# Is it possible to obtain light intensity information for a surface using Matlab's 'light' function?

Tags: matlab, lighting, surface, phong

In Matlab, we can create a basic surface with flat face lightning using the following:

```
peaks(10)
light
```

This creates the following picture:

[image: Peaks]

Is there a way to obtain the matrix indicating light intensity on the surface patches for the current view? Alternatively is there a way to simply obtain the FaceColor attribute which is being applied to the individual patches on the surface (I assume that from subtracting this FaceColor from the unlit FaceColor, we can obtain intensity)?

Answer (score 1):

After you call peaks a surface object is defined. So after you run

```
peaks(10)
light
```

you can find this object with

```
s = findall(gcf,'Type','surface');
```

form here you can convert the surface to a patch object and get the vertex colors by

```
fv = surf2patch(s.XData,s.YData,s.ZData,s.CData);
fvcdata = fv.facevertexcdata;
```

in the figure you created matlab uses flat shading from the per vertex colors, thus the face colors are calculated from the vertex colors and the angles of the light source with the face normals, which is equivalent to

```
patch(fv,'FaceVertexCData',fvcdata,'FaceColor','flat'); light
```

> Update

I looked at the [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#prop_FaceColor) of the FaceColor property. If it's defined as 'flat' and the FaceVertexCData is defined per vertex then matlab will choose for each face the color of the first vertex of the face.

Thus to get the effective per face color you can do this:

```
c = fvcdata(fv.faces(:,1)); % per face color
[cmin,cmax] = caxis;
cmap = colormap;
m = length(cmap);
index = fix((c-cmin)/(cmax-cmin)*m)+1;
%Clamp values outside the range [1 m]
index(index<1) = 1;
index(index>m) = m;
faceColors = cmap(index,:);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it's the light data that I want (or alternatively the effective Face Color (not the CData from the surface object). Is there a way to find out Matlab's algorithm for flat shading (or any other shading) based on the vector normal and light source vector? Is it simply some sort of scalar scaling where if the vectors are tangential, the value is 1 and if the vectors are perpendicular, the value is 0?

Comment: I looked at the matlab documentation of the FaceColor property. If it's defined as 'flat' and the FaceVertexCData is defined per vertex then matlab will choose for each face the color of the first vertex of the face. I updated my answer to show you how to get the effective face color.

Comment: Sorry, but we might be confused: when the light hits the surface, the previous facecolor of the patch (call it FaceColor1) will be changed to a different colour (call it FaceColor2). This is what I referring to as the "effective color". From what I understand of your update, you were explaining how FaceColor1 was found by interpolating the vertex values. Put it another way. Is there a way to call a patch object with exactly the same color as a *lit* patch but without calling the light command?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you want to explicitly calculate the shading for each face (phong shading)? I only gave you the face material colors. you need to define the camera and light locations and the model transformation. I will update my answer accordingly.